Postfix cannot access Opendkim Socket
I have a ubuntu 20.04 server and a domain example.com
I installed postfix and opendkim via apt.
In /etc/opendkim.conf I have
Socket local:/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock

The file exists.
$ ls -l /run/opendkim/opendkim.sock
ls: cannot access '/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock': Permission denied
$ sudo ls -l /run/opendkim/opendkim.sock
srwxrwx--- 1 opendkim opendkim 0 Oct  4 21:19 /run/opendkim/opendkim.sock

I added postfix to opendkim group.
$ groups postfix
postfix : postfix opendkim

I also tried reboot by sudo reboot.
When I do this
echo "This is the body of the email." | mail -s "Subject of the Email" test-04pbmr33x@srv1.mail-tester.com

But I got this error.
Oct 04 23:58:24 ubuntu postfix/cleanup[52998]: 
warning: connect to Milter service local:/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock: No such file or directory

I took a closer look
$ ps -p 52998 -o pid,comm,user,%cpu,%mem,stime,tty
    PID COMMAND         USER     %CPU %MEM STIME TT
  52998 cleanup         postfix   0.0  0.2 00:00 ?

The user is postfix and it should have access to the socket file, but the system journal says no.

Postfix runs chrooted, so you need to put opendkim socket into postfix chroot.
Socket      local:/var/spool/postfix/var/run/opendkim/opendkim.sock


Thanks. I edited /etc/opendkim.conf and changed the line and then the problem is fixed.
